# Nagle algorithm in tcp/ip

Tags: tcp, packet

can u kindly explain me the concept of nagle algorithm in tcp/ip,with an example?

Answer (score 3):

I think [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) does a nice job in its opening paragraph.

> Nagle's document, Congestion Control in IP/TCP Internetworks (RFC 896) describes what he called the 'small packet problem', where an application repeatedly emits data in small chunks, frequently only 1 byte in size. Since TCP packets have a 40 byte header (20 bytes for TCP, 20 bytes for IPv4), this results in a 41 byte packet for 1 byte of useful information, a huge overhead. This situation often occurs in Telnet sessions, where most keypresses generate a single byte of data which is transmitted immediately. Worse, over slow links, many such packets can be in transit at the same time, potentially leading to congestion collapse.
>
> Nagle's algorithm works by combining a
>   number of small outgoing messages, and
>   sending them all at once.
>   Specifically, as long as there is a
>   sent packet for which the sender has
>   received no acknowledgment, the sender
>   should keep buffering its output until
>   it has a full packet's worth of
>   output, so that output can be sent all
>   at once.